# clang 5.0 pdb support as of 2017

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, clang, pdb-files

Here it is explained that clang now knows how to produce .pdb files (http://blog.llvm.org/2017/08/llvm-on-windows-now-supports-pdb-debug.html).

As far as I understand, at least clang with Microsoft linker is now expected to produce .pdb files equivalent to those produced by the msvc toolchain.

It is explained here how you can use mainstream Visual Studio 2017 to debug an "external" binary, that is one not built using projects/solutions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-an-executable-not-part-of-a-visual-studio-solution).

I have compiled a simple hello world application with `clang -g main.c -o main.exe` which produced a .pdb file as expected.

However, when I try to step into it, Visual Studio complains that the .pdb file does not contain line number information.

In contrast, compiling with `cl /EHsc /Zi main.c` allows to debug with Visual Studio normally.

I am currently trying to understand if clang ecosystem is already good enough for developing on Windows, and will appreciate if somebody can explain:

1. What is the difference between .pdb files produced by stable clang and msvc?
2. Is there any difference between `link` and `lld` for that matter?
3. Are things going to change in clang 6.0?

Comment: Maybe you should run `clang-cl.exe`?

Comment: Stupid question: If you are already on Windows and have access to Visual Studio, why not just use Visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
clang -g -gcodeview main.c -o main.exe
```

The option `-gcodeview` tells Clang to generate debugging information in Microsoft's [CodeView format](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2016-11/Slides/Kleckner-CodeViewInLLVM.pdf).
Visual Studio can then read the resulting `.pdb` without problems.

Another option would be to use `clang-cl`, which you can pass `/Zi` to, or [MIEngine](https://github.com/Microsoft/MIEngine), which should allow you to use non-CodeView debugging information in Visual Studio.
I haven't tried neither of those, though.

---

For the record, this was my **main.c**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    getc(stdin); // pause to allow attaching the debugger
    return 0;
}
```

I used [Clang 6.0.0](http://releases.llvm.org/6.0.0/LLVM-6.0.0-win64.exe).